# automate color palette generation?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcgis-desktop, visualisation, color

I frequently am in need of color gradients that aren't readily available through ArcGIS or the ColorBrewer add-in. I find the process of manually creating gradients in Arc very tedious: saved custom colors don't come up in the edit color ramp window.

I am wishing that there was some way to use Python to batch generate colors ramps for ArcGIS. For example, if I gave it a "high" color and a "low" color, it could create and import a linear gradient between the colors. Importing might simply be a matter of saving to a specified directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 10.1 provides a function, however I haven't found a functional work around in 10.0

See the [`GraduatedColorsSymbology`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000005z000000) class in the arcpy.mapping module.